# MySQL Update big amount of html content issue

Tags: php, mysql, html

I've created autosave via Ajax for my content management system. Having problem. Problem is,  when i'm testing on my local server, the php side updates big piece of data easily but when i'm testing it on my webhost, I see that, if the updated content is a big data, then php doesn't update the table row on the first attempt, updates only after second attempt. Any suggestion? How to deal with that problem?

PHP Side

```
<?php
session_start();
require '../../core/includes/common.php';
$err=array();
$name=filter($_POST['name'],$db);
$id=$db->escape_string($_POST['id']);
$title=filter($_POST['title'], $db);
$parentcheck=$db->escape_string($_POST['parentcheck']);
if(isset ($_POST['parent'])) $parent=$db->escape_string($_POST['parent']);
else $parent=$parentcheck;  
$menu=$db->escape_string($_POST['menu']);
$content = html($_POST['content'], $db);
if (!isset($content)) die('error');

$result=$db->query("UPDATE pages AS p, menu AS m SET m.parent='$parent', m.name='$name', m.showinmenu='$menu', p.id='$id', p.title='$title', p.content='$content' WHERE m.id='$id' AND p.id=m.id") or die($db->error);


if ($result){   
echo "{";  
echo '"msg": "Success" ';
echo "}";  
}
else{ 
echo "{"; 
echo
'"err": "Error"';  
echo "}";  
}

?>
```

Comment: how BIG is your data?! I don't think that it is possible to exceed the php execution time limit with saving a simple html string. Maybe your database column on the server is to small and the error is not displayed or something like that... besides this we might need some code examples ;-)

Comment: Is your php giving any warning or error?

Comment: no. i'll update my question. check out please

Comment: it return success, and i'm tracking all processes with firebug. Php returns no error, but doesn't update db table. Strange. I can't find the wrong code, logic. It works perfect on my local server

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like you can have tons of potential errors, this example should only show what you can do to always return something back which *might* be in the format your AJAX request can deal with:

You're mixing two types of error handling: die'ing straight away and reporting your action result to AJAX. You should do the one way *or* the other, this one is reporting back always:

```
<?php
session_start();
require '../../core/includes/common.php';

...

if (!isset($content)) die('{"err": "No content"}'); // This will never happen BTW.

$result = $db->query("UPDATE pages AS p, menu AS m SET m.parent='$parent', m.name='$name', m.showinmenu='$menu', p.id='$id', p.title='$title', p.content='$content' WHERE m.id='$id' AND p.id=m.id");


if ($result)
{   
    echo '{"msg": "Success"'}';
}
else
{ 
    echo '{"err": "Error"}';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this, parse the html content for only the important content ie the div and not the entire page, Mysql text datatype supports 2GB, but its not safe to overload mysql.

Idea 1
Can you by any chance save the HTML content on an XML and refer the link along with the node in the Mysql Column so that AJAX picks up the xml and the node to display data on the fly.

Idea 2
Gzip the content and store in Mysql